# Resizing image using BufferedImage.getSubImage()

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

So i'm working on a component that crops images, and it works fine.

**If** the image is bigger than its parent container (which can only be `max-width: 100vw`), the `div` that selects a portion of the image to be cropped, has the `x,y,width,height` that will be used in  `BufferedImage.getSubImage(x,y,width,height)`.

**The problem:** When this happens, the `x,y,width,height` will be relative to the **resized image rendered** but **not to the real image**, thus the portion of the image selected will not be the same when passed to the `getSubImage` method, and this causes a different part of the image to be `cropped`.

I tried to use a proportion way to calculate the `pixels per resized image` but this causes too many  exceptions depending on the area that has ben selected.

Any ideas? Thanks.

BTW the real code is not posted because it is rather long and is being used with `JSF` and I know this is irrelevant to the problem.

Code:

[Here's an image showing the component working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONPjp.jpg)

When the ok button is clicked it all boils down to this:

```
 public String processImage() {

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(completeImg);

        HttpSession ses = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        ImageContainer curIc = (ImageContainer) ses.getAttribute("ic");

        try {
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(bais);

            // all values showld be calculated now in relation
            // to the real images's  dimensions.
            x *= bi.getWidth();
            y *= bi.getHeight();
            width *= bi.getWidth();
            height *= bi.getHeight();                

            BufferedImage bi2 = bi.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bi2, "jpg", baos);

            croppedImg = baos.toByteArray();

            curIc.setCroppedImageContent(croppedImg);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msgs",
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "ioexception", "error processing image"));
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your question looks to be nothing more than a basic math issue. Please boil your code down to the essentials that shows where and how you're doing your calculations. Without seeing what you're doing, it will be difficult to know what you could be doing wrong. Also is this Java or JavaScript? And are you sure?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, question eddited.

Comment: what are the initial values of the fields x,y,width,height? What are these values after multiplication of width and height of bi? What is the Dimension of bi?

Comment: @daniel, this varies depending on the image.

Comment: Well one example would be nice. Otherwise it would just be guessing. Simply log this values on an example image.

Comment: I bilieve the example isn't important, no matter what size, he wants the area selected to be the same even though the selected area is a `%` smaller in the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is unsolvable as you pose it:

if W is the width of the real image
and w the displayed image 
you want to calculate the offset X at the real image
while you have the x offset in the displayed image

you could do X=(W/w)*x

but since w is missing it can't be calculated

if you can take a screen shot of the image displayed on the web page then you have w -

this is my understanding of what you say

--

its a simple problem of math

if you know w from javascript

then the proportion factor is W/w

instead of doing

x *= bi.getWidth();

you do

x *= bi.getWidth()/w;

and so on for y

this new x is the X the crop offset at the real image (on file)

try and see if it gives you the correct result

so you have

```
x *= bi.getWidth()/w;
y *= bi.getHeight()/h;
width *= bi.getWidth()/w;
height *= bi.getHeight()/h;
```

w and h is what you get from javascript

Comment: I can get the dimensions for both images, the one displayed on the web page via javascript and the original with bufferedImage.getWidth/height. Can you please elaborate ? I'm not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: I tried this according to your aswer but it still renders a different area: 

`x = (bi.getWidth() / imgWidth) * x;`

`y = (bi.getHeight() / imgHeight) * y;`

`width = (bi.getWidth() / imgWidth) * x;` 

`height = (bi.getHeight() / imgHeight) * y; `

`BufferedImage bi2 = bi.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);`

Comment: is imgWidth what the user views? or javascritp is picking what is supposed to display?

Comment: ok isee an error width = (bi.getWidth() / imgWidth) * x should be width = (bi.getWidth() / imgWidth) * width